# std::string to int8_t

Tags: c++

This gives a bad_lexical_cast exception:

```
int8_t i = boost::lexical_cast<int8_t>("12");
```

I would like to have an exception when the value doesn't fit in an `int8_t`.

How should I do this? Should I cast to an int first and throw an exception if the value falls outside the range -128 to 127?

I'm also interested in converting strings to uint8_t.

Comment: The `bad_lexical_cast` is already an exception, why not catch that and then if you want, throw your own exception?

Comment: Of course, use of `int8_t` is not portable. It is "optional", i.e., implementations are not required to provide it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Q: What does lexical_cast of an int8_t or uint8_t not do what I expect?
>
> A: As above, note that int8_t and uint8_t are actually chars and are formatted as such. To avoid this, **cast to an integer type first**

Source:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/frequently_asked_questions.html

Answer (score 4):

`lexical_cast` of a `int8_t` or `uint8_t` is treated as a char.

You can combine `lexical_cast` with [`numeric_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/numeric_cast.html) to get what you want:

```
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using boost::lexical_cast;
using boost::numeric_cast;

numeric_cast<int8_t>(lexical_cast<int>("128"));
numeric_cast<uint8_t>(lexical_cast<int>("256"));
```

Comment: Cool! I can now write a conversion functor which takes a reference to the value of the desired type and the string from which to convert.